# Why Symfony start server on random port (all except 8000)? WSL2 Ubuntu-20.04

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, wsl-2

I run `symfony serve`, Symfony tell me that started server on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, but this port not work (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`).

But on terminal below Symfony say: `[Web Server ] May  7 18:31:38 |INFO   | PHP    listening path="/usr/bin/php7.4" php="7.4.3" port=35823` and adress `http://127.0.0.1:35823` is working.

The port is always different every `symfony serve` run.

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNr5U.png)

Info about enviroments:

PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2022 15:36:52) ( NTS )

Symfony CLI version 5.4.8

Composer version 2.3.5

Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: @lorenzo_campanile — I haven't decided yet

Comment: so have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Because port 8000 is already used by another service
you can check by this all ports by this commande

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

Or only port 8000

```
lsof -i :8000
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I get empty result after exec this commands.
But when I run ```symfony serve``` result is not empty: 
```symfony 4318 timshaq   11u  IPv6  16828      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)```
```php7.2  4331 timshaq    4u  IPv4   1269      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:46093 (LISTEN)```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. But even if I try to serve on another port (for example `symfony serve --port=55588`), it will still serve on another random port that's different every time...

[image: My example]

In this example, `127.0.0.1:55588` doesn't work, but `127.0.0.1:42311` works.

Comment: Found a solution: I installed php-fpm, and it still didn't work on 127.0.0.1:8000 but it did work using localhost:8000